# Getting error on inserting webbrowser inside panel in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, webbrowser-control, panel

i am developing an application in which i require to insert a webbrowser inside a panl.while doing this i am getting error inside desginer code "Unable to get the window handle for the 'WebBrowser' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported."for which i have put the code to run it inside STSthread.but after that i am getting error of "cross thread.."

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(newThreadStart(MethodToCallCOMMethod));
newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newThread.Start();
private void MethodToCallCOMMethod()
        {
            this.webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            this.webBrowser2 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();

            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                                {
                                    this.p_bottom.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser2);

                                }));
            }
            else
            {
                this.p_bottom.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser2);
            }
        }
```

after using invokerequired i am still getting "cross thread error:-control'' access from another thread that it was created in c#",how to solve it..?please help me.

Comment: All child controls must be created by the same thread.  So this cannot work.  You need to address the real problem, whatever it might be.  Click the Ask Question button to get help with it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are creating the WebBrowsers in a different thread, in general you should never create or edit controls outside the gui thread.

So either create the webBrowser1 and 2 somewhere else (in the GUI Thread) or put the code inside the MethodInvoker delegate (which runs in the GUI Thread)

If it says `the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment` then either your Main function doesn't look like this (what VS creates by default) or you tried to create them from another thread:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: initially i created webbrowsers inside the same thread but then i got the error of "ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment."so,i had to use the seperate thread.but than i am getting the cross thread error..

Comment: The GUI Thread is a STA thread. unless you changed you program.cs (where the main form gets started). did you do that? Are you sure you tried to create the controls in the GUI thread?

Comment: and i have not changed my program.cs

Comment: well, i cant tell you anymore because there is not enough code. but when i create a new WindowsFormsApplication in VS and add the WebBrowser control everything works fine. You must have an error somewhere else if you say that creating the webbrowser in the gui thread didn't work for you

Comment: then you will have to show more code because as i said, i works without problem for me. but i get the exact same exception `current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment` if i try to create the WebBrowser from another Non-STA Thread or if i remove the `[STAThread]` attribute. => you are doing something wrong but i can't tell from your code