# can't insert webbrowser inside panel in c#winapp

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, panel

I am unable to add webbrowser control to panel in winapp,getting this error"Unable to get the window handle for the 'WebBrowser' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported."i also tried to do it using STAthread like

```
Thread uy = new Thread(me_p);
uy.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
uy.Start();

private void me_p(object obj)
{
//throw new NotImplementedException();
this.p_bottom.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser2);         
}
```

Comment: how often do you want to ask this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting error on inserting webbrowser inside panel in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820005/getting-error-on-inserting-webbrowser-inside-panel-in-c-sharp)

Comment: yes i have asked that ,but i didn't get answer so tried to explain it in different way..

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when done this way

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
    this.webBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
    this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // panel1
    // 
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser1);
    this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(47, 149);
    this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
    this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
    this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
    // 
    // webBrowser1
    // 
    this.webBrowser1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.webBrowser1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.webBrowser1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
    this.webBrowser1.Name = "webBrowser1";
    this.webBrowser1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
    this.webBrowser1.TabIndex = 0;
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
    this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1;
```

You can have a browser pre initialized and later use it in your threads.